# Is there an easy way to transfer reports/schedules from an SSRS 2005 server to a different SSRS 2008 server?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

We have a ton of SSRS2005 reports, which I intend to transfer to our new SSRS 2008 server.  I'd rather not do this manually...

Actually, we've got some SSRS2000 reports on a third server as well, so if anyone knows of a tool or technique for doing all these transfers I pay in upvotes! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but [Reporting Service Scripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62) may can help you.